# Was this character a traitor or were they trying to just provoke Gaitonde?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, sacred-games

In the season 2 of "Sacred Games", towards the end, we see

> Jojo telling Gaitonde that she was never on his side and that she had been working for the Guruji - all done to take him on a pre-decided path and bring him to the place he is this day.

This question arose because from a lot of conversations between the both of them through out the show, she showed a lot of inclination to kill herself and at one point asked Gaitonde to kill her.

> She also smiled after he killed her.

So was this character trying to provoke Gaitonde to get to kill her (in a twisted way she wanted to be dead and get killed by him) or was she really a double agent?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think she betrayed Gaitonde. Mainly because of 2 reasons

1. If she was involved in the whole 'plan', she would have known the reason behind Gaitonde hiding the money in her apartment.
2. Trivedi tells Gaitonde that he sent Jameela which is totally wrong because when Gaitonde asks Bunty to send Jameela to Kenya, he says there is some payment left which shows Bunty was dealing with Jojo for Gaitonde and not Trivedi.

Answer (score 1):

**[Jojo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surveen_Chawla) was a traitor.**

Although her relation with [Ganesh Gaitonde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nawazuddin_Siddiqui) was good during the whole second series of *[Sacred Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacred_Games_(TV_series))*, but she had hidden the fact from Gaitonde of her support to [Guruji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pankaj_Tripathi). Even though her support to Guruji/Malcolm had not been shown in any episodes of Sacred Games but it has been revealed by her at the end to Gaitonde.

**Jojo didn't provoke Gaitonde to kill her.**

The character of Jojo was quite blunt by nature. In whole episodes, whatever she was talking with anyone, had been shown as true or straight forward nature of her. According to her nature it seems that she was not lying at the end to Ganesh Gaitonde. Even though Jojo was the responsible person for the death of her younger sister and tried to attempt suicide 4 times, but attempting suicide was a reflection of regret for the event of her sister's death since she used to recall that event multiple times. She was the person who didn't has fear of her death. (Following conversation of her with Gaitonde indicates this fact)

> Gaitonde - "*Maut ko dekha hai kabhi, face to face?*"
>
> Jojo - "*Tere jitna nahi dekha, lekin jab bhi dekha hai datt ke khadi hai samne.*"

Since [L.K.Trivedi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chittaranjan_Tripathy) was trying to kill her by putting his hands around her neck, still she was speaking with him normally and bluntly.

Her work was to control the violent behavior of Ganesh Gaitonde (assigned to her by Guruji) so that it would not make harm to their aim. When Gaitonde got suspicious on her, then only she told him the truth.

> Jojo - "*Ha mai hai unke sath*"
>
> Gaitonde - "*Kiske sath?*"
>
> Jojo - "*Pehale din se. Vo sab bole mere ko Gaitonde ko lagaam deni hai*"

She also smiled after getting first gun shot by Gaitonde because she got why Gaitonde is killing her, i.e. due to betrayal behavior of her with him. And she was quite happy because she was successful of fooling the big goon like Ganesh Gaitonde since 20 years. Jojo got the address of Ganesh Gaitonde and she was about to tell this address to Malcolm so as to kill Gaitonde. Immediately after the betrayal of her, Gaitonde killed her as he was very much sad about her behavior. Still she was trying to go towards door. And in second gun shot she got dead. At this time, she didn't provoke Gaitonde to kill her, but it was the real blunt nature of Jojo to speak with anyone.

Before Gaitonde, she was in contact with Guruji and all. So, she was following their instructions only. Remember, she didn't call Ganesh Gaitonde initially (many times) but instead, Gaitonde phoned her first time for getting [Jamila](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elnaaz_Norouzi) for [Purushottam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saanand_Verma). After this Gaitonde called her many times on phone.

> Gaitonde - "Bambai ka yaad nahi jarela tha, aur Bambai yaad aata tha to aapun Do log ko phone lagata tha. Ek Jojo aur dusra tha Dilbag Singh"

Jojo didn't know Trivedi when he first came to her house. It indicates that even though she was in contact with Aashram, she might be speaking directly to Guruji or directly to Malcolm.

Gaitonde kept faith on Jojo and she has shown betrayal behavior to Ganesh Gaitonde. 
**The character of Jojo was a traitor.**

**Update** - As per comment given below this answer, I am updating/extending this answer.

1. Gaitonde had hidden lots of money at Jojo's home. Still Jojo had not given 
   this money to Malcolm. She didn't know Why Gaitonde is hiding so much money 
   in her home. The following communication indicates this:

> Gaitonde (self talk) - "Plan ko rokne ka ek hi tarika bacha tha. Paisonko rokna"
>
> Jojo - "Gaitonde, ye sab kya lafda hai?"
>
> Gaitonde - "Tera Suraksha Jakit hai, Chinta mat kar, sab thik kar de ga mai"
>
> Jojo - "aree par bigda kya hai ye to bata"

Still, Gaitonde didn't tell her his plan to stop the money to Malcolm. So, she was unaware of this plan and she was not suspicious about the relevance of money. She thought that the money is owned by Gaitonde. So, she didn't tell Malcolm about the hidden money.

Answer (score 0):

I think she was both. She wasn't lying about the guilt of her sister's death, she was punishing herself everyday. She had tried to commit suicide many times and confessed before the priest. Jamila also confirmed this when she came to her to safeguard her passport to Jojo.

I think she was asked by Malcolm to provide `service` to Gaitonde just because she used to provide professionals for that.

I think Jojo and Guruji connection was nothing but professional relationship. Note Jojo had all the money Gaitonde kept by her and still she didn't give away that money to Guruji, nor she said anything about that to Trivedi when he came to her home and threatened her to get her arrested by the cops.

Comment: I don't doubt her back story or her suicidal tendencies at all. thats all true. Is there a solid source or a scene from any of the episodes that establishes that Jojo was a double agent ? You answer eludes that point is my feeling..